# How can i select a text in a div , whose content has a scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, textselection

My intention is to select a text in a div which has a scroll.I need to scroll inside that div and forcefully select a text.

I am using the below given code.

```
  createSelectionFromPoint(startX, startY, endX, endY) {

        var doc = <any> document;
        var documentBody = <any>doc.body;
        var start, end, range = null;
        if (typeof doc.caretPositionFromPoint != "undefined") {
          start = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(startX, startY);
          end = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(endX, endY);
          range = doc.createRange();
          range.setStart(start.offsetNode, start.offset);
          range.setEnd(end.offsetNode, end.offset);  

        } else if (typeof doc.caretRangeFromPoint != "undefined") {

          start = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(startX, startY);
          end = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(endX,endY);
          range = doc.createRange();
          range.setStart(start.startContainer, start.startOffset);
          range.setEnd(end.startContainer, end.startOffset);    

        }
        if (range !== null && typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
          var sel = window.getSelection();
          sel.removeAllRanges();
          sel.addRange(range);   

        } else if (typeof documentBody.createTextRange != "undefined") {
          range = documentBody.createTextRange();
          range.moveToPoint(startX, startY);
          var endRange = range.duplicate();
          endRange.moveToPoint(endX, endY);
          range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", endRange);    
          range.select();
        }




  }
```

The error message i am getting is

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'startContainer' of null

Comment: Please `console.log(start)` just before the error line. (after `end = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(endX,endY);`)

Comment: I consoled it. The result is "null"

Comment: try `console.log(startX + ' ' + startY)` in the same position